# Including or in grep pattern

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want to grep a word wrap in single quote or double quote

eg.

```
"myWord"
'myWord'
```

I am using

```
grep -rn "\"\|\'myWord\'\|\""
```

this should allow `"myWord" , 'myWord" , "myWord' and 'myWord'` , but it is not working, what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for:

```
grep -rn "[\"']myWord[\"']"
```

Your approach would be:

```
grep -Ern "(\"|')myWord(\"|')"
```

You can go slightly more advanced so that you don't allow `'myWord"`:

```
grep -Ern "(\"|')myWord\1"
```

The problems with yours are:

- | is for extended regular expressions
- | will apply to the whole pattern if not in parenthesis
- ' doesn't need to be quoted